# Subscriptions with Paypal IPN - how to disable specipic transaction type

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a process that happens only after getting An "Verified" IPN from PayPal.
When The user signs up for Subscriptions, I get 2 IPNs: one for **subscr_signup** and one for **subscr_payment**. this launch my process twice

How can I prevent it?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't prevent it. You react to the messages correctly, instead of incorrectly as you are doing now. `subscr_signup` does not imply a payment. It is an opportunity for you to register the user. `subscr_payment` is a payment event that you should export to the accounting system. You need to know about both events. You cannot elide them.

Comment: You also need to know about reversals, reinstatements, payment failures, expiries, and cancellations. If you're just going to run your business on the `subscr_payment` events alone you will end up with more money in your books than you really have, and you will be servicing clients who haven't actually paid.

Comment: The majority of custom IPN listeners in existence were only written so far as to automatically handle new payment events, leaving other event types to be manually reconciled with email/account notifications and the account interface and reports

Comment: @PrestonPHX You have evidence for that claim? Mine was certainly written to process *every* message.

Comment: Nothing wrong with one having been written with that functionality, I've just seen enough to know that most do not do anything with non payment messages. Today no one should be writing new IPN listeners anyway so the point is moot, apart from quick fixes like the OP's question any new work that actually requires asynchronous notification should use the Webhooks service instead.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I prevent it?

Add an `if` statement to your process which checks whether the value of the transaction type is `subscr_payment`.

Comment: So then he doesn't get to find out about reversals, reversal-reinstatement, cancellation, expiry, ...

Comment: Such process handlers, if of interest and if something is going to be done with them, quite clearly belong in an `else if` condition. It's impossible to do anything meaningful with non-payment IPNs if you do not first check their type.